# jQuery popup window + dynamic content, no database

Tags: jquery, html, css

I'm restricted from using a database on this project and being relatively new at Jquery, I'm curious if there's a why to dynamically populate a popup window via Jquery, depending on what the end user clicks. Anyone have an example for me to learn from?

Comment: [FancyBox](http://fancyapps.com/fancybox/) + ajax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm! What are you trying to do.

To make it as simple as possible just add two handlers like this:

$("#button1").click(function() {

$("mydialogTest").html("Hello from button 1");
   $("#myDialog").dialog("open");

});

$("#button2").click(function() {

$("mydialogTest").html("Hello from button 2");
   $("#myDialog").dialog("open");

});

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the standard [`window.open()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_open.asp) function and open the page in a new window using [`Querystrings`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) to populate its content. (By the way, this is standard javascript, jQuery doesn't have a separate function to open child windows).